# Using latest PowerShell SDK in VB - System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException

Tags: vb.net, powershell, powershell-7.0

I am updating an older app which used `System.Management.Automation.dll` v10.0.10586 from `NuGet` e.g. `PowerShell 3.0`

My new app is `.NET 5` and I have added v7.1.0 of both System.Management.Automation and Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK from NuGet

But running basic code to test which worked fine with old version doesn't work with new, and I am confused

For example, the code snippet below gives an error

```
Dim ps As PowerShell = PowerShell.Create()
ps.AddCommand("test-netconnection")
Dim result = ps.Invoke()
MsgBox(result(0).Properties("PingSucceeded").Value.ToString)
ps.Dispose()
```

Error:

> "System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException: 'The
> 'test-netconnection' command was found in the module 'NetTCPIP', but
> the module could not be loaded."

Please can someone advise why what worked before doesn't work now?

I have tried from a standard `PowerShell 7` console and `test-netconnection` works fine

Comment: In PowerShell 7, you'll want `Test-Connection`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - no I don't, they are two completely different commands - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/test-netconnection?view=win10-ps  and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-connection?view=powershell-7.1

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, and it wasn't anything to do with running the wrong command!

Despite it working fine in PowerShell console, when running it in VB it was failing because I needed to firstly run `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` or `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`

Visual Studio debugger was crashing and showing an error, but the main error it was showing e.g.

> "System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException: 'The
> 'test-netconnection' command was found in the module 'NetTCPIP', but
> the module could not be loaded."

was not very helpful, but on further examination one of the inner exceptions mentioned execution policy so after adding the below to my code it now works fine

```
powershell.AddCommand("Set-ExecutionPolicy").AddParameter("Scope", "Process").AddParameter("ExecutionPolicy", "Unrestricted").AddParameter("Confirm", False).AddParameter("Force", True).Invoke()
```